# How can i change the position of the days(number) in tkcalendar

Tags: python, tkcalendar

I am looking to move the number of the days in each square from the middle to the top left. I have read through the documentation of tkcalendar, and i have not been able to find anything online. I have not been able to try anything since i still have yet to see any examples where this is done. Could someone help me with this if it is possible?

[image]
python version = 2.7.16

system = macOS Mojave 10.14.6

coding level = noob - beginner

Thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Python 2.7 has lost its support as of 2020. Why don't you update to 3.9.

Comment: I have a folder that says Python 3.9 ( i downloaded it recently after deleting all the old python installations i could find) but Terminal tells me my python version is 2.7. Im probably doing something wrong but i suppose this is a question for another time. @CoolCloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no option to change the position of the day numbers. Therefore, it is necessary to dig into the source code of the widget to do it. The days are just labels so it is possible  get the desired position by setting their `anchor` option to `"nw"`. They are stored into a list of lists called `._calendar` (one list per week):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkcalendar import Calendar

class MyCalendar(Calendar):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        Calendar.__init__(self, master, **kw)

        for row in self._calendar:
            for label in row:
                label['anchor'] = "nw"

        # # uncomment this block to align left weekday names
        # for label in self._week_days:
        #     label['anchor'] = "w"


root = tk.Tk()
cal = MyCalendar(root, showweeknumbers=False)
cal.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
root.geometry("400x300")
root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]